# Constraints $X^TBX = 1$, what's the maximum $X^TAX$?

Tags: linear-algebra

(a) Find the maximum value of $X^TAX$ subject to the constraints $X^TX = 1$. (A is a $n * n$ symmetric matrix)

It is easy to solve (a) by using spectral decomposition.

(b) Let A, B be $n * n$ symmetric matrices.  By using (a), Find the maximum value of  $X^TAX$ and $X$ subject to the constraint is $X^TBX = 1$

How to find?

Comment: Why should there be a maximum?

Comment: @0 Hong Do you still assume that $X^TX=1$ in part (b)?

Comment: Do you know if $B$ is also positive definite?

Comment: @AnyAD I don't know.. but is (b) possible to solve if assume $X^TX = 1$  in part(b)?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $B$ is invertible. Set $x=B^{-1/2}y$, then $\left\langle x,Bx\right\rangle =1\Longleftrightarrow\left\langle y,y\right\rangle =1$.
Thus, 
\begin{align*}
\left\langle x,Ax\right\rangle  & =\left\langle y,B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}y\right\rangle ,
\end{align*}
and 
\begin{align*}
\max_{\left\langle x,Bx\right\rangle =1}\left\{ \left\langle x,Ax\right\rangle \right\} 
\end{align*}
is the largest eigenvalue of $B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: can you maximise $x^2+ay^2$ subject to $x^2+by^2=1$? Yes, iff $a,\,b\ge 0$. Working in a basis that diagonalises $B$, how in general do the signs of its eigenvalues matter?

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to $\max f(x)=x^tAx$ with constraint $g(x)=x^tBx-1=0$. By Lagrange multiplier, to find critical point we solve following equation for $(\lambda,x)$
$$\nabla f=\lambda \nabla g,\ \ \ \ \ \ g(x)=0$$
Here $\nabla f=2Ax$ and $\nabla g=2Bx$. (Try to understand why we get such calculations).
Then above equation becomes
$$Ax=\lambda Bx$$

(1) if $B$ is invertible (notice that symmetric doesn't imply invertible), then $B^{-1}Ax=\lambda x$, that means solution $x^*$ is eigenvector w.r.t. eigenvalue $\lambda$. Thus
$$f=(x^*)^tAx^*=\lambda (x^*)^tBx^*=\lambda\leq \max \lambda_i$$
Thus the maximum of $f$ is just the maximum eigenvalue of matrix $B^{-1}A$.

(2) If $B$ is not invertible, we can't move $B$ to the left. But we still have $(A-\lambda B)x=0$. To solve this system, note that we want a nonzero solution $x$. So by basic linear algebra, we must have
$$det(A-\lambda B)=0$$
Therefore we can solve $\lambda^*$, then 
$$f=x^tAx=\lambda^* x^tBx=\lambda^*$$
In conclusion, comparing above results and choose the maximum one.